# How to have my twitter timeline in my website

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi

I've been searching through the twitter API but can't find the right docs. What I need is not a simple timeline to embed on the website. I need to be able to allow visitors to the site to reply to tweets and also enable a follow button on the embedded timeline.

Are these functionalities possible on the twitter API? Especially the one allowing visitors to reply on the embedded timeline.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction and any examples would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write the code, but the API supports all of these things:

1. For a timeline, here are a couple to look at:

   - The [Home Timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline), or
   - The [User Timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline)
2. Use [statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) to reply.
3. Use [friendships/create](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/post-friendships-create) to follow.